# Freemarker call Java Method on Maps or Lists

Tags: java, freemarker

I have an object which extends from HashMap and put it into freemarkers data model. Now every time when i try to call a method on this object freemarker tries to access a key inside the map instead which will cause an error. I got the same issue with objects that extends from ArrayList. Is there a way to call the Java methods of this objects instead of accessing their keys?

Here is an exampel:
The object I would like to put into the data model:

```
public class ObjectInDataModel extends HashMap<String, String> {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private boolean bSuccess;

   public ObjectInDataModel(boolean bSuccess) {
      this.bSuccess = bSuccess;
   }

   public boolean isSuccessful() {
      return bSuccess;
   }

}
```

The freemarker code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <#if object.isSuccessful() == true>
            <h1>Success</h1>
        <#else>
            <h1>Fail</h1>
        </#if>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I try to process it I will get the following error:

```
09:10:59,458 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) org.auctores3.fw.util.ActFwRuntimeException: freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
09:10:59,458 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) ==> object.isSuccessful  [in template "test" at line 5]
```

Because Freemarker tries to access a key called isSuccessful instead of calling the method isSuccessful().

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: Better now ... I am not familiar with that framework ... the first thing i am wondering: why do you extend HashMap? Are there use cases that work "better" when the model is a hashmap? Instead of your Model class maybe implementing some interface, and *owning* a hashmap, instead of deriving from it?

Comment: It is just an example. In my real Object I would override the get Method and stuff like that. It is important to have a Map so that freemarker can work with it as a map.

Comment: Ok, then the other way round: what is they point of these special methods?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this: `myMap?api.someCustomMethod()`. `?api` will expose the Java API of the `Map` (or `List`) instead of the map keys (or list items).

Note that with the default configuration of FreeMarker `?api` is not available. See here how to enable it:
https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html#ref_buitin_api_and_has_api